# Multiple Android Activity Instances are slowing down my game

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a game that switches between a StartScreen Activity and the Game Activity. When you complete a level you go back to the StartScreen, and then click to go back to the Game Activity and play the next level. Problem is, on each new level the frame rate is decreasing...from 30, to 20ish to 15ish.....

I am allowing the run thead to close by setting a boolean to false, and then when it breaks the "while" loop the Intent is made to go back to the StartScreen Activity.

I've tried attributes singleInstance, noHistory, and also finish()with the Intent, with no luck....

any ideas?....

Comment: in game you can use customview that extends from surfaceview and load each time the level in customview you don't need here more activities

Comment: Any ideas on how to make it perform better, or close all of the extra activities?

Answer (score 2):

You can finish the StartScreen activity after launching your Game activity, or, use [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) when returning from Game activity.

The flag has the following behavior:

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

Comment: ClearTop is what I would use.

Comment: Appears that setting the activity attributes to "singleInstance" did the trick.